# Way to update and keep a browser in custom android device

Tags: updates, browser, custom-roms

We have custom android terminal and it comes without Google Apps and only few system apps are there and without a browser app. We need to install a browser in the device and keep it updated. Will it be possible?

Update: I can not flash this rom to add GApps.

Comment: Without Google play store you can't install apps and its further updates for your android device(standard and secured method). You can install apk of any app on your device. Install apk of any app provider resource and install browser from it. So you can get updates from app provider.

Comment: I can not flash this rom to add GApps

Comment: Download apk's of Google play store, play services framework, Google services framework and install to device. And then you can run play store and install any apps.

Comment: http://en.miui.com/thread-416299-1-1.html try to install using second method (follow steps under update heading)

Comment: Play Store alternative resources https://medium.com/pen-bold-kiln-press/best-google-play-store-alternatives-30c759de1c26